# Join Function in SQL

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have a query that joins about 5 tables and displays all the results.  The records show on the web application it should have around 70000 entries however when I do this join it only displays 51000 entries in MSSQL 2008.  I was wondering how I can manipulate the join functions to display all the 70000 entries perhaps adding an outer join or an inner join?  I don't have too much experience with the join function and was hoping for someone to edit my query for it to display all entries in those 5 tables.  I know this is a quick fix for an expert progammer and I appreciate the time and effort in advance! Cheers

Existing Query:

```
   select SerialNum as [Serial Number],ts_sitename As Site,(case m.Scratched
   when 0 then 'Live'
   when 1 then 'Free'
   END) as Status,  Note as Comment, 
   SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Effective Date Added], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Effective Time Added], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Scratched Date], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Scratched Time], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Purge Date], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Purge Time], 
   fl_filename as Dataset, hs_hostname,UserCode
   from (((((Media m join TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) 
   join MediaGenT g on m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) 
   join TheHosts_tab h on mg_hostnum = h.hs_hostnum)
   join TheFiles_tab f on mg_filenum = f.fl_filenum)
   join [User] u on mg_usernum = u.UserId)
   join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId 
   where Destroyed = '0';
```

Comment: without knowing more about your data one can only postulate that you should consider using an OUTER JOIN ...

To help you more, please share which table has 70000 rows (is it Media) or some other?

Comment: This is just a guess, but you should probably LEFT JOIN the Note table, as I'm guessing that Notes does not necessarily exist in the Media table. Using a LEFT JOIN on the Note ensures that you get all rows from Media, even those that have no note.

Comment: @Dan can u post that as an answer so i can test it please

Comment: @omarK - well, it's not exactly an answer, just a guess. We have to know more about your tables and the relations between your tables to come up with a qualified answer. But feel free to test it anyway - just replace: `join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId` with `left join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId`

Answer (score 0):

Try the same, but use `OUTER JOIN` on instead of `JOIN`

```
select SerialNum as [Serial Number],ts_sitename As Site,(case m.Scratched
   when 0 then 'Live'
   when 1 then 'Free'
   END) as Status,  Note as Comment, 
   SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Effective Date Added], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(EffectiveDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Effective Time Added], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Scratched Date], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ScratchedDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Scratched Time], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 1, 8) AS [Purge Date], 
   SUBSTRING(cast(ChangedPurgeDate as char), 10, 6) AS [Purge Time], 
   fl_filename as Dataset, hs_hostname,UserCode
   from (((((Media m join TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) 
   OUTER JOIN MediaGenT g on m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) 
   OUTER JOIN TheHosts_tab h on mg_hostnum = h.hs_hostnum)
   OUTER JOIN TheFiles_tab f on mg_filenum = f.fl_filenum)
   OUTER JOIN [User] u on mg_usernum = u.UserId)
   OUTER JOIN Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId 
   where Destroyed = '0';
```

Comment: this gives me an error on Line 13
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` keyword used alone defaults to an `INNER JOIN`, which joins based on the intersect.

I don't know much about your data set, but if you're excluding data that you don't think you should be excluding, you should be using a more inclusive join. Try replacing your `JOIN` keywords with `OUTER JOIN`s.

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a good resource for learning about `JOIN` semantics to figure out which one suits your needs best, and also lets you try out different kind of `JOIN` statements yourself to get more comfortable.